# has_many method does not work after renaming model and table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had modelA, which `has_many modelBs` and modelB `belongs_to modelA`. I tried to change the name of a modelB to modelC without really knowing what I'm doing. Before I could call `@modelA.modelBs` just fine and get a list of objects, but now I can't call `@modelA.modelCs`. I get a NoMethodError. These are the things I did to try to make the switch:

I renamed the table with a sqlite3 migration:

```
def change
  rename :modelBs, :modelCs
end
```

Then I change modelA so that it `has_many :modelCs` and I renamed and edited `modelB.rb` (now `modelC.rb`)and changed the class name so that it's `class ModelC < ActiveRecord::Base`. It still `belongs_to :modelA`

Rails can't find a bars method to call on an instance of ModelA. I get a NoMethodError when I do `@modelA.modelCs`. I ran the migration, I restarted the server. What am I missing? Did I do a bad thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you do a `$rake db:reset`?  db:reset is supposed to rebuild the database with all of the seed data (without the migrations); maybe check this and see what the dependencies are like at this point, then you can run your `$rake db:migrate` to run the migrations and see what your left with there.  Can you include more information about your backend?  Is it Sqlite3? PostgreSQL?

- **db:migrate** runs (single) migrations that have not been run yet.
- **db:reset** does db:drop, db:setup

Comment: Pretty sure rake db:reset did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

did the migration run successfully and did your table actually get renamed?  I have always used rename_table for this:

```
def change
  rename_table :modelBs, :modelCs
end
```

Inside your class, you can also tell rails which table the model should be associated with, just to test whether it's looking at the right table

```
class modelC < ActiveRecord::Base
   table_name "modelCs"
end
```

hope that helps